# How can I fix the 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'origin' of undefined' error in AWS Lambda function?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I trying to test an lambda function in AWS where an answer is inserted in a table. I have attached the security policy. I have made sure that the questionID in the UpsertAnswer lambda matches the questionID of the UpsertQuestion lambda. But I keep getting an error that says:

```
"errorType": "TypeError",
  "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'origin' of undefined",
  "trace": [
    "TypeError: Cannot read property 'origin' of undefined",
    "    at responseHeaders (/var/task/index.js:32:26)",
    "    at /var/task/index.js:124:22",
    "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)"
  ]
```

What could be causing this error?

Here is the code:

```
/**********************************************************************
 *  Upsert Answer item into table
 **********************************************************************/

/* POST test
  {
    "resource": "/",
    "path": "/",
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "body": "{\"answer\":\"This is my super important answer\",\"questionSlug\":\"this-is-my-super-important-answer\"}"
  }

  PUT test - make sure to change the ID to one in your database before running or this method will create a new record
  {
    "resource": "/",
    "path": "/",
    "httpMethod": "PUT",
    "body": "{\"answer\":\"This is my super important answer\",\"negativeVotes\":0,\"positiveVotes\":1,\"id\":\"5ec9957e3f64b70004e7599e\"}"
  }
*/

// we need access to the AWS SDK
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

// we need uuid to generate unique ids
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");

//  we need access to DynamoDB and choose the DocumentClient model
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

const responseHeaders = (headers) => {
  const origin = headers.origin || headers.Origin;

  return {
    // HTTP headers to pass back to the client
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    // the next headers support CORS
    "X-Requested-With": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
      "Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,x-requested-with",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": origin,
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,*",
    Vary: "Origin", // for proxies
    // the "has-cors" library used by the Angular application wants this set
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
  };
};

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  // get the HTTP Method used
  var httpMethod = event.httpMethod;
  // get the HTTP body sent
  var payload = JSON.parse(event.body);

  // time to prepare the upsert
  const paramQuery = async () => {
    // define our query
    let params = {
      TableName: "Answer",
      Key: { id: "" },
      UpdateExpression: "set #qi = :qi, #a = :a, #nv = :nv, #pv = :pv",
      ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        // define the attributes used in the update expression
        "#qi": "questionId",
        "#a": "answer",
        "#nv": "negativeVotes",
        "#pv": "positiveVotes",
      },
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        // set default values
        ":qi": "",
        ":a": "",
        ":nv": 0,
        ":pv": 0,
      },
      // this tells DynamoDB to return the new records with all fields, not just the changed ones
      // see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html for
      // information on the possible values
      ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW",
    };

    // these three fields can be set during create or update
    //  set the answer if there is one
    if (payload.answer && payload.answer.trim())
      params.ExpressionAttributeValues[":a"] = payload.answer;

    //  set the category slug if there is one
    if (payload.questionId && payload.questionId.trim())
      params.ExpressionAttributeValues[":qi"] = payload.questionId;

    if (httpMethod == "PUT") {
      // PUTs are updates but the ID is passed as a path paremeter
      // lets get the path parameters
      let pathParameters = event.pathParameters;

      //  set the unique key of the item to be modified
      params.Key.id = pathParameters.id;

      // these two values are only changed - they are always defaulted during create
      //  set the negativeVotes
      params.ExpressionAttributeValues[":nv"] = payload.negativeVotes;

      //  set the positiveVotes
      params.ExpressionAttributeValues[":pv"] = payload.positiveVotes;
    } else {
      // POSTs are inserts
      // create and set the unique key. its a uuid without the '-'
      var id = uuidv4().replace(/\-/g, "");
      params.Key.id = id;
    }

    // uncomment the next line to see the parameters as sent to DynamoDB
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(params));

    // we create a promise to wrap the async DynamoDB execution
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var queryParams = docClient.update(params).promise();
      queryParams
        .then(function (data) {
          resolve({
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            // HTTP headers to pass back to the client
            headers: responseHeaders(event.headers),
          });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  };
  // we await our promise here and return the result (see the resolve above)
  return await paramQuery();
};
```

I tried adding quotes around origin in the properties section, and was expecting data returned. But I still got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented out

```
const origin = headers.origin || headers.Origin;
```

and

```
 "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": origin,
```

and it looks like my problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

The argument `event.headers` seems to have no value as the error says it is undefined. How about checking the structure of `event` again and trying the argument `event` instead of `event.headers`?